# Select input hide text when direction is RTL

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an html `<select>` with `direction: rtl;`

The problem is that the beginning of the text is hidden.

The problem is related to the number of items `<option>` in the list. when I remove one item, the text is not hidden anymore.

You can see an example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17b4ydfc/4/)

**Here is my code:**

```
<div>
    <select id="ddlArea">
        <option value="-1">-- Select --</option>
        <option value="3">Sport</option>
        <option value="4">Electronics</option>
    </select>
    <select id="ddlBrand">
        <option class="ddlBrandItemFirst" value="-1">-- Select --</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_6" value="9">111111</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_6" value="10">222222</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_6" value="12">333333</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_5" value="13">444444</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_4" value="14">Digital Camera</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_4" value="14">Computers</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_4" value="14">Hard Disk</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_4" value="15">Gadgets</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_2" value="16">555555</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_5" value="17">666666</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_6" value="18">CFMOTO</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_1" value="19">777777</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_6" value="20">888888</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_1" value="21">999999</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_2" value="22">100000</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_1" value="23">rrrrr</option>
        <option class="ddlBrandItem area_11" value="5555">eeeeeeee</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#ddlBrand').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#ddlProduct').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
$('#ddlArea').on('change', function () {
    // Enable
    $('#ddlBrand').removeAttr('disabled');

    //hide all items in ddl
    $(".ddlBrandItem").hide();

    // show only items for this areaId
    $(".area_" + this.value).show();

    // show the first option (show all)
    $('.ddlBrandItemFirst').prop('selected', true);
});

$('#ddlBrand').on('change', function () {
    // Enable
    $('#ddlProduct').removeAttr('disabled');
    //hide all items in ddl
    $(".ddlProductItem").hide();

    // show only items for this areaId
    $(".brand_" + this.value).show();

    // show the first option (show all)
    $('.ddlProductItemFirst').prop('selected', true);
});
```

**Style:**

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: use `text-align: right;` instead...

Comment: text-align:right: is not affecting.

Comment: I added the code. I realized that the problem related to the number of <option> items in the <select>. when I remove one item the text is not hidden anymore.

Comment: What text is hidden where? And why are you using right-to-left direction when the content is in a left-to-right language? What is really the *desired* appearance and functionality?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <div style="width: 525px; margin:auto; padding-top: 25px;">
    <select dir="rtl" id="ddlArea">
        <option dir="ltr" value="-1">-- Select --</option>


        <option dir="ltr" value="3">Sport</option>
        <option dir="ltr" value="4">Electronics</option>

    </select>

    <select dir="rtl" id="ddlBrand">

                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis </option>
        <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis </option>
        <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis </option>
        <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis </option>
        <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis </option>
        <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis </option>
        <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis </option>
        <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">BasketBall</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="6">Soccer</option>
                <option dir="ltr" class="ddlBrandItem area_3" value="7">Tennis </option>


    </select>


    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17b4ydfc/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use following css

```
#ddlBrand{
    direction:ltr;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/17b4ydfc/7/)